# variable usage in expect script

Tags: shell, unix, expect

Text of attribute.csv
"dog","6"
"cat","3"
"mikeymouse","10"

```
firstScript.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start Say"
read a
while((1))
do
    echo -n "Master: "
    read animal
    if [[ $animal = "dog" ]];then
        echo "Age: 6"
    elif [[ $animal = "cat" ]];then
        echo "Age: 3"
    elif [[ $animal = "mikeymouse" ]];then
        echo "Age: 10"
    fi
done

secondScript.sh
#!/bin/bash
export line=`wc -l ~/Desktop/attribute.csv | awk {'print $1'}`
expect -c '
    set timeout 3
    spawn /Users/dog/Desktop/firstScript.sh
    expect {
        "Start Say" {send "\r";exp_continue}
        "Master: " {
            for {set i 1} {$i<=$env(line)} {incr i} {
                send [exec bash -c {awk -F '\''"'\'' {'\''print $2'\''} ~/Desktop/attribute.csv | sed -n "$i"p}]\r
            }
            interact
        }
        timeout {puts "\nTimeout";exit 0}
    }
'
echo ""
```

actual outcome：
$ /Users/dog/Desktop/secondScript.sh
spawn /Users/dog/Desktop/firstScript.sh
Start Say

Master: dog
cat
mikeymouse
Age: 6
Master: Age: 3
Master: Age: 10
Master: dog
cat
mikeymouse
Age: 6
Master: Age: 3
Master: Age: 10
Master:

$

The problem is I cannot get my expect result as below:
$ /Users/dog/Desktop/secondScript.sh
spawn /Users/dog/Desktop/firstScript.sh
Start Say

Master: dog
Age: 6
Master: cat
Age: 3
Master: mikeymouse
Age: 10
Master:

Comment: Expect uses the [Tcl language](http://www.tcl.tk/) which has different syntax from shell. If you are more comfortable with shell syntax you can try my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Comment: @Max : You put the whole expect program between single quotes, which means that `$2` is not expanded by your shell.  I would put a Tcl script of this size into a seperate file. Note that you can pass parameters to Tcl in the same way as to any other programming language, and I would use this to forward $2 from the shell to your expect-script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. mixing expect into a shell script, you're best using a quoted heredoc to avoid quoting hell
2. you don't need to exec out to awk and sed, Tcl can easily read a file
3. single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl, use braces instead.
4. CSV can be surprisingly tricky to get right, use a well tested library.
5. smart to use the environment to pass data into expect.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export csv=$HOME/Desktop/attribute.csv
expect <<'END_EXPECT'
    # from tcllib
    package require csv

    set fh [open $env(csv) r]
    while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
        lappend animals [lindex [csv::split $line] 0]
    }
    close $fh

    set timeout 3
    set idx -1

    spawn $env(HOME)/Desktop/firstScript.sh
    expect {
        "Start Say" {send "\r"; exp_continue}
        "Master: " {
            if {[incr idx] == [llength $animals]} {
                exit
            }
            send "[lindex $animals $idx]\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        timeout    {puts "\nTimeout";exit}
    }
END_EXPECT
echo ""
```